# passport.js || Error at Strategy.passport.use.LocalStrategy [as _verify]

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I've trying to create a login using passport but I'm having some issues.

First, take a look at my code:
`

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const pool = require('../database');
const helpers = require('../lib/helpers');

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true         
}, async (req, username, password, done) => {
    const { fullname } = req.body;
    const newUser = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        fullname
    };
    newUser.password =  await helpers.encryptPassword(password);
    const result = await pool.query('INSERT INTO users set ?', [newUser]);
    console.log(result);
}));
```

`

As you can see, I'm trying to print an "OkQuery" that says that everything went perfect.

But that's not the case because of this error.

`

```
 Error
       at Pool.query (/home/theivano/Escritorio/Personal/Practicas_Uni/TFG/myapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
       at Strategy.passport.use.LocalStrategy [as _verify] (/home/theivano/Escritorio/Personal/Practicas_Uni/TFG/myapp/src/lib/passport.js:22:31),
```

`
PD: the database receives the newUser correctly! I checked!

Comment: I would look at those line numbers in each of the 2 scripts to see what that code is and look at it really hard .. might be a typo or fat finger .. never hurts to look.  If you got a line number, that is your problem, but have to see why.

Comment: @easleyfixed the second error references to the ''' const result = await pool.query ''' from above! Still, I'm gonna try to find the error really hard. Thanks for ur response!

Comment: @easleyfixed I just fixed it. I only needed to add  `const result = await pool.query('INSERT INTO users set ?', [newUser], (err, resultado) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.id = resultado.insertId;
        //return done(null, newUser);
    }); `

Comment: Nice job!  I would post your comment as an Answer and MARK it the answer since it seems to be the correct solution for this.